# How to give permissions to specific users in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I'm really complaining about this. I created a bucket in S3, this specific bucket is intended for a "dev" environment, so I would like only certain users to be able to operate with it, BUT also, that they can go to the browser and paste the url of the object (e.g. an image) and can see it, tried this, the user can operate through CLI but when he goes to the browser with the url of the object he still gets an access denied.

As I mentioned, I would like only certain users, either through arn, or whatever, to be able to see the objects or the web page in the browser, and not the entire public.
Could someone help me configure permissions like this?

These are the ones I currently have, but this way I keep getting access denied even though I specify the arnlike

[image]

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1234567890123",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Statement2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::dev-panel",
            "arn:aws:s3:::dev-panel/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::USERID:user/USERNAME"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}